# Input to array of strings won't show?

Tags: c, for-loop, format

I'm in C and I'm supposed to have an input of numbers (don't know how many) formatted into one column without storing them into an array of integers. I can't figure out why my code won't read the input and out put it. Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    char *nums[400];

    for (i=0; i<nums; i++) {
        scanf(nums[i]);
        printf( "%.*s", 3, nums[i] );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're using scanf incorrectly.  Right now it is trying to read a format specified by nums[i] into no variables.  Also, the comparison between i and nums is incorrect.

Comment: You haven't allocated any space for `nums[i]`, so you're causing undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of 400 pointers, but you've never initialized them. Instead, you could declare a 2-dimension array:

```
char nums[400][4];
```

Then you're trying to use `nums` as a limit to the `for` loop. What you actually want is the number of elements in `nums`, which is `sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0])`; or you could define a macro that specifies the size of the array.

Next, you left out the format string argument to `scanf()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#declare SIZE 400

int main()
{

  int i;
  char *nums[SIZE][4];

  for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){

    scanf("%3s", nums[i]);
    printf( "%.*s", 3, nums[i] );    
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Baramar correctly and thoroughly explained your main problems, I think I might have a different understanding of your problem. You want a given string of number, e.g.: `2134567896543245678` and print it out in a single column, neatly formated in rows of three digits each like that:

```
213
456
789
654
324
567
8
```

without an intermittent array of integers.

That could be done like e.g.: this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 512

int main()
{

  int res;
  // for the scanf input, set all to '\0'
  char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE + 1] = { '\0' }, *idx;
  size_t len, i;

  // restrict max-size to BUFFER_SIZE
  res = scanf("%512s", buffer);
  if (res != 1) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } else {
    if (strcmp(buffer, "exit") == 0) {
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    // TODO: check if the buffer contains all digits
    len = strlen(buffer);
    idx = buffer;
    for (i = len; i >= 3; i -= 3, idx += 3) {
      printf("%.3s\n", idx);
    }
    // last entries, if any
    if (*idx != '\0') {
      printf("%s\n", idx);
    }
  }
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

If you get actual integers in a row like e.g.: `12 3123 23478 34 5456 567456 567 678` you can use something like that:

**EDIT**

After the comment by the OP to use floating points I changed the code to accept input of the form:

```
24722.319352                51433.662233
     56087.991042             49357.684934  67875.375848      68421.563197

54521.615295

22744.470483

38097.001461    80878.250982
92131.575748                7217.137271
20750.671365 7620.695008 37118.391541   28655.609469    46885.110202    87114.202312
46462.577299








20557.716648
```

And the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXNUM 400
int main()
{
  int res;
  int i = 0, m;
  // input and two temporary variables
  double in, in1, in2;

  for (m = 0; m < MAXNUM; m++) {
    res = scanf("%lf", &in);
    if (res != 1) {
      break;
    } else {
      switch (i) {
        case 0:
          // set value of first temporary variable to input
          in1 = in;
          // increment indicator indicating position in output row
          i++;
          break;
        case 1:
          in2 = in;
          i++;
          break;
        case 2:
          // print the three numbers and a newline
          fprintf(stdout, "%f %f %f\n", in1, in2, in);
          // reset counter
          i = 0;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  // if there are still numbers, print them
  if (i != 0) {
    if (i == 1) {
      fprintf(stdout, "%f\n", in1);
    } else {
      fprintf(stdout, "%f %f\n", in1, in2);
    }
  }
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Try it out with

```
 $ gcc-4.9 -O3 -g3  -W -Wall -Wextra  -std=c11 sc.c -o sc
 $ ./sc < floatin 
 24722.319352 51433.662233 56087.991042
 49357.684934 67875.375848 68421.563197
 54521.615295 22744.470483 38097.001461
 80878.250982 92131.575748 7217.137271
 20750.671365 7620.695008 37118.391541
 28655.609469 46885.110202 87114.202312
 46462.577299 20557.716648
```

If you enter less than 400 entries you need to end with `EOF` which can be triggered in most Unix shells with `ctrl+d` or set an entry to end the entries like e.g.: `-1` if all you have is positive numbers and check for it to break out of the loop. If you submit a file like in the example above it works automatically.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but the input I will be receiving are numbers like 4356.34543543 and separated by whitelines.

Comment: The `4356.34543543` I understand, just use `scanf("%f",&in)` and use `double` (or `float`) for the variables holding the numbers. But what are "whitelines"? Is there an empty line between every number? Please add an example input to your post (you can format it like code to show whitespace etc.)

Comment: Whitelines as in spaces, tabs, etc. Here is an example.
https://gyazo.com/30a6e016c1a0c9a3b6007354ee532e1c

Comment: @BrettMalmquist please don't use images, text is better to C&P. Thank you. Changed the code (the last one) to accept floating point values. Is that more to your taste?

Comment: Last question, is there any possible way to line up the decimal places in each column?

Comment: @BrettMalmquist yes, but that gets complicated, you need to know where the period is. You could change the `printf()` formats for example, to print an exact amount of digits before and after the period (may not work with trailing zeros). Or use `%e`. Otherwise you need find the size of the integer part (in decimal) to find the position of the period and fill up with spaces/tabs accordingly. Won't be easy, especially because you do not know the size of the biggest one.